# Android filter 'mp3' files

Tags: java, android

I am working on a Media player app. I've added a listview to show the 'mp3' files from Storage, I've added a feature by which we can exclude which files we do not want to show. Ex- 'Call-recording, Mic-Recordings', we can type the filenames and separate it by comma.

Here's the function which fetch all the mp3 files but I am unable to implement the filter for excluding the files.

```
public ArrayList<File> fetchSongs(File file, String exclFiles){
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        File [] songs = file.listFiles();
        
        String [] cParts = exclFiles.split(",")

        if(songs !=null){
            for(File myFile: songs){
                if(!myFile.isHidden() && myFile.isDirectory()){
                    arrayList.addAll(fetchSongs(myFile, exclFiles));
                }
                else{
                    if (myFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") && !myFile.getName().startsWith(".")) {
                        arrayList.add(myFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

How can I implement the filter for excluding files, I tried using for-loop but It didn't worked well...

Also all the filename which I want to exclude are in cParts variable in the form of list

Edit: I just want it to be simple, like if the 'mp3' file name start with the element in cParts then I don't want to show it...

Comment: Is the result list empty? Do u have the storage permission? Try to break down the problem, e.g. by outcommenting all parts that are unnessesary for now (exclFiles, cParts) and printing out the names of all files in songs and after that in the else{} statement.

Comment: I have the storage permission, and I am getting the the final result like this, ```mySongs = fetchSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), curExcludeFiles);``` here curExcludeFiles variable contains the filename that user don't want it to show, like- "Call-record, Voice-record", if there are more than 1 filename then we can seperate it with comma... And finally we get the 'MP3' files present in External Storage but I can't filter the filenames that user want to exclude in the fetchSongs function!